# How can I have a custom order in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

In Snowflake, how do I define a custom sorting order.

To try to explain what I want consider this table:

```
ID  Language    Text
0   ENU         a
0   JPN         b
0   DAN         c       
1   ENU         d
1   JPN         e
1   DAN         f
2   etc...
```

here I want to return all rows sorted by Language in this order: Language = ENU comes first, then JPN and lastly DAN.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 4):

Using CASE expression and associating value for each language:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
ORDER BY ID, CASE LANGUAGE WHEN 'ENU' THEN 1 WHEN 'JPN' THEN 2 WHEN 'DAN' THEN 3 END
```

Or [DECODE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/decode.html) function:

```
ORDER BY ID, DECODE(LANGUAGE, 'ENU',1, 'JPN', 2, 'DAN', 3)
```

Comment: Thank you! I edited my question, I would like to order by language, in this order: ENU, JPN, DNA, and so on:
ENU, JPN, DNA,ENU, JPN, DNA,ENU, JPN, DNA

Comment: @user3461502 Then swaping the orderr CASE, ID is the way to go

Comment: Hmm I tried this, but then I get this order; ENU, ENU, ENU, JPN, JPN,, JPN, DAN, DAN, DAN

Comment: @user3461502 The provided ID, CASE in the answer procudes ENU, JPN, DAN, ENU, JPN, DAN etc.

Comment: For anyone interested in a default value, just append it (`4`) at the end `DECODE(LANGUAGE, 'ENU',1, 'JPN', 2, 'DAN', 3, 4)` as per the docs https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/decode#syntax